# Is there any way to look at the raw header from ring?

Tags: clojure, ring

Is there a way to turn ring's hash-map of parameters into the original response and request headers that the browser and server use to communicate?

So basically, instead of the hash-map structure that ring provides, I want to be able to generate and parse the raw text headers using ring.

Request:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__qca=P0-1122510804-1338534864474; usr=t=pvgxSE5uUO9s&s=Ir7otYoeUaMb; __utma=140029553.119380626.1338534864.1340057197.1340064637.52; __utmb=140029553.6.10.1340064637; __utmc=140029553; __utmz=140029553.1340000628.50.23.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
```

Response:

```
Host:stackoverflow.com
If-Modified-Since:Tue, 19 Jun 2012 00:10:35 GMT
Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11092804/edit
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.34 Safari/536.11
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:public, max-age=60
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:33233
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 19 Jun 2012 00:26:48 GMT
Expires:Tue, 19 Jun 2012 00:27:48 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 19 Jun 2012 00:26:48 GMT
Set-Cookie:usr=t=Qz5ObGDYskmu&s=Ir7otYoeUaMb; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Wed, 19-Dec-2012 00:26:48 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary:*
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you are asking. You can access the request headers in your routes (and set your own). There is a ':headers' key in the request map, and you can set your own in the response map.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Ring provides that because purpose of Ring is to create the abstractions over the HTTP request/response using hash map and other abstractions and even if ring provide you the low level access to headers strings, that would be a leaky abstraction. If you really want to access raw headers and generate raw response headers than you can use a web server like jetty interface directly rather than going though ring.